# Powershell Compare date from CSV with todays date

Tags: powershell

I have a csv file with a date when the last appointment was made formatted as 30-01-2018.
Project name    Client number   Client name Date last appointment   CCP nr  CCP lastname    CCP mail

i want to send an email if the Date last appointment is 10 months ago so they have 2 months to schedule a new appointment. 
The mail should go to ccp mail and if thats empty to the project name.
I have a script that looks good but i cant get date date format.

I read everywhere about parse but i dont get it if i dont't convert it i get random users not within the last two months and if i try to convert it i get
Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

```
$CheckDate = (Get-Date).Addmonths(-10).tostring("dd-MM-yyyy")
$data = Import-Csv -Path '.\CCPt.csv' -Delimiter ";" 
foreach ($User in $data)  {

$Project = $user.'Project name'
$clientname = $user.'Client name'
$datelast = $user.'Date last appointment'
$mail = $user.'CCP mail'


$from = "mail@domain.com" 
$smtp = "smtp.domain.com" 
$Subject = "Reminder"
$body = "Client $clientname has to make a new appointment"
$projmail = Get-ADUser -filter { Name -eq $Project } -Properties * | select -    ExpandProperty mail 

$Convertdatelast = ([datetime]::ParseExact($datelast,"dd-MM-yyyy",$null))

If ($datelast -lt $CheckDate) {send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $smtp -To $mail -    cc -From $from -Subject $subject -Body $body -BodyAsHtml }
}
```

Comment: Why so complicated? `$Convertdatelast = Get-Date $datelast` does the job.

Comment: @Paxz That depends on the own date format. Possibly you need to replace $null with `System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture`. But the main problem is that the first line converts the back date to a string which isn't comparable as a date. So Jim_NL remove the ToString part.

Comment: Are you sure your CSV contains only date (no additional spaces at the beginning/end)? `ParseExact` should work here, but keep in mind what @LotPings wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to Convert the current Date to a string for comparison and you don't have to use such complicated parsing methods.

```
$CheckDate = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-10)
$datelast = Get-Date ($user.'Date last appointment') #given the format is something like "30-01-2018"
```

You then just compare both variables with `$datelast -lt $CheckDate`.